# Unittesting - Mocking/suppressing an object's __init__

Tags: python, python-unittest

Let's say I'm using a library's abstract class as a base for my own abstract base class, so

```
class LibBaseClass():

    some_var = None  # In any non-abstract versions of this class, this must be set

    def __init__(self):
        if some_var is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("some_var Not set!")
```

Now I have my own base class that uses this class...

```
class MyBaseClass(LibBaseClass():

    some_var = None  # Still None, doesn't make sense for this var to be set to anything

    def my_additional_method(self):
        ....
```

Now when I come to test MyBaseClass, in the `setUp()` method, I want to initialise the class, so:

```
my_class = MyBaseClass()
```

but of course this will raise the error from the library's base class **init**(). I'm looking for the neatest way around this issue but I'm not at all sure what to mock. The error isn't important/won't effect any of the tests I write and run, so I just need a way of sidestepping this particular error.

Comment: Does `__init__` do anything else besides checking for that var?

Comment: No, it's just there as a "Hey you haven't configured your child class properly" warning basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have a design problem here:

`some_var = None  # In any non-abstract versions of this class, this must be set`

`some_var = None  # Still None, doesn't make sense for this var to be set to anything`

Those two statement contradict each other.
So you should set some_var or stop rasing an exception when it is not set.
Also, if MyBaseClass is supposed to be abstract you should not instantiate it.

EDIT:

However if you **really** know what you are doing you can easily drop parent `__init__`:

`MyBaseClass.__init__ = lambda self: None`

Comment: I agree it is a design flaw, I would not normally put a configuration error in the __init__ method like that, but rather have it in the method where it is required. What should I set `some_var` to in my child-yet-still-abstract class though? To add a little context, `some_var` is an html file template to render to. MyBaseClass will never be used as a standalone, so it doesn't make sense for it to have a template.

Comment: Something to think about anyway, I found this:  http://blog.devork.be/2008/12/mocking-away-init-method.html That also covers the issue.